# IJCAD上でWindowFormを呼び出した際のTabStopについて

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2019を用いた.NETアプリケーションの開発をしております。

Application.ShowModelessDialog()で
WindowsFormで作成したダイアログを呼び出したところ、
呼び出したダイアログ上でTabキーを押してもフォーカスが移動しませんでした。

Tabキーでのフォーカス移動を有効にするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

各コントロールのTabStopはTrueとなっています。

```
    public class Class1
    {
        [CommandMethod("Test")]
        public void DoIt()
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            GrxCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.ShowModelessDialog(form);
        }
    }
```

[image: Tabキーでフォーカスが移動しない]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IJCADの.NET APIで作成したウインドウをモードレスで呼び出した場合、TABでフォーカスは移動されないようです。
モーダルでは大丈夫そうなので、恐らく.NET APIの不具合だと思われます。
IJCADのサポートに、APIの不具合として報告した方が良いと思われます。

余談ですが、WPFを使用して作成されたウインドウは大丈夫なようです。
この際、ShowModelessDialogでなく、ShowModelessWindowで呼び出す必要があります。